# NServiceBus & ServiceInsight Sql Server Transport & Persistence

Tags: sql-server, nservicebus, serviceinsight

The application we have been building is starting to solidify in that the majority of the functionality is now in place.  This has given us some breathing room and we are starting evaluate our persistence model and the management of it.  I guess you could say the big elephant in the room is RavenDB.  While we functionally have not experienced any issues with it yet, we are not comfortable with managing it.  Simple tasks such as executing a query, truncating a collection, etc, are challenging for us as we are new to the platform and document based NoSql solutions in general.  Of course we are capable of learning it, but I think it comes down to confidence, time, and leveraging our existing Sql Server skill sets.  For example, we pumped millions of events through the system over the course of a few weeks and the successfully processes message were routed to our Audit queue in MSMQ.  We also had ServiceInsight installed and it processed the messages in the Audit queue, which chewed up all the disk space on the server.  We did not know how to fix this and literally had to delete the Data file that we found for RavenDB.  Let me just say, doing that caused all kinds of headaches.

So with that in mind, I have been charged with evaluating the feasibility and benefits of potentially leveraging Sql Server for the Transport and/or Persistence for our Service Endpoints.  In addition, I could use some guidance as well for configuring ServiceControl and ServiceInsight to leverage Sql Server.  Any information you might be able to provide regarding configuring these and identifying any draw backs or architectural issues that we should consider would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, Jeffrey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SQL persistence requires very little configuration (implementation detail), however, using SQL transport is more of an architectural decision then an infrastructure one as you are changing to a broker style architecture, that has implications you need to consider before going down that route.

ServiceControl and ServiceInsight persistance:

Although the ServiceControl monitors MSMQ as the default transport, you can use ServiceControl to support other transports such as RabbitMQ, SqlServer as well, [Here you can find the details of how to do that](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/wiki/Multi-Transport-Support)

At the moment ServiceControl relies on RavenDb for it's persistence and it is not possible to change that to SQL as ServiceControl relies on Raven features.(AFIK)
 There is an open issue for expiring data in ServiceControl's data, see [this issue in github](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/116)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ServiceControl usage of RavenDB (this is the underlying service that serves the data to ServiceInsight UI):

As Sean Farmar mentioned (above), in the post-beta releases we will be including message expiration, and on-demand audited message deletion commands so that you can have full control of the capacity utilization of SC.

You can also change the drive/path of the ServiceControl database location to allow it to use a larger drive.

Note that ServiceControl (and ServiceInsight / ServicePulse that use it) is intended for analysis, debugging and operational monitoring. Its intended to store a limited amount of audited data (based on your throughput and capacity needs, this may vary significantly when counted as number of messages, but the database storage capacity can be up to 16TB).

If you need a long term storage for audited data, you can hook into ServiceControl HTTP API and transfer the messages' data into various long-term / unlimited-size / low-cost storage solutions (e.g. http://aws.amazon.com/glacier).

Please let us know if this answers your needs and whether you have additional questions

Danny.